# Hibernate many to one mapping

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am doing a proof of concept for one to many mapping with no success. My schema is as follows: User -----> UseRole

```
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="UserRole")
public class UserRole {

    private int userRoleId;
    private String userRoleName;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "UserRoleId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getUserRoleId() {
        return userRoleId;
    }

    public void setUserRoleId(int userRoleId) {
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
    }

    @Column(name = "UserRoleName", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getUserRoleName() {
        return userRoleName;
    }

    public void setUserRoleName(String userRoleName) {
        this.userRoleName = userRoleName;
    }

}
```

and here a part of the User class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Users")
    public class User {
    private int userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private UserRole userRole;
    private List<Meeting> meetings;
    private List<MeetingInvitation> meetingInvitationsSend;
    private List<MeetingInvitation> meetingInvitationsReceived;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "UserId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
         .... 

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=UserRole.class)
    @JoinColumn (name="userRole")
    public UserRole getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

}
```

and i am getting this error 
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on User.userRole references an unknown entity: UserRole

ass you can see i added the @Entity annotation at the user Role class

Answer (score 5):

You probably just forgot to declare the class in your hibernate config file:

```
<mapping class="com.foo.bar.UserRole"/>
```

Also, note that the `targetEntity=UserRole.class` is unnecessary, since your getter returns a `UserRole`. Hibernate will deduce the target entity from the return type of the getter.

Comment: indeed i just found it out myself by i couldn't submit the answer, but many many thanks